# How to give an asp button a specific shortcut

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, keyboard

Q:

Is there some way to capture (specific key(`keyboard stroke`)) ,when the user clicks it as he clicks the specific `button` i want.

I want to do that , because i have a `grid view` with an `insert button` in the gridview footer (to create a new row),and for facilitation, instead of using the mouse every time to add a new row, i wanna to capture a specific key as an equivalent to this button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can create specific combinations of keyboard strokes to give you shortcuts.

A typical example would be to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save some data on the page.

Here is a good tutorial on how to do it with javascript and jQuery http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/126/how-to-create-ctrl-key-shortcuts-in-javascript/

Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
var isCtrl = false;
document.onkeyup=function(e){
    if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=false;
}
document.onkeydown=function(e){
    if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
    if(e.which == 83 && isCtrl == true) {
        //run code for CTRL+S -- ie, save!
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but the link doesn't appeared. Is it a valid link?